# LibreOffice Writer: hotkey to Insert Row above

Tags: libreoffice

Right click and finding two submenues is extremely slow.
Is there any way to do it with keyboard combination?

Version: 5.1.6.2
Build ID: 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial10
CPU Threads: 12; OS Version: Linux 4.4; UI Render: default;

Comment: LO Writer or Calc? Please [edit] your question with version of ubuntu and version of LO for completeness

Comment: @24601 Thank you, I've edited. In Calc the one click and one choice is needed, I meant Writer

Comment: Does [this LO resource](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.1/en-US/text/swriter/04/01020000.html?DbPAR=WRITER) help with preset shortcuts? I see that Alt+Enter = Inserting a new paragraph directly before or after a section, or before a table

Comment: @24601 just Alt+Enter does nothing with table

Comment: It works on LO Writer 7.3.3.2 but the short key is actually AltGr+Enter (or Right Alt) not left Alt+Enter.

Answer (score 0):

In `Libre Office Writer` version 7.3.3.2/LO Community the key shortcut to insert a new paragraph directly before or after a section is <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> according to your keyboard layout).